# Dart, Flutter: indices of range

Tags: list, flutter, dart, range

How can I get indexes of a range I got by a value not indexes?
For example:

```
["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"].getRangeIndexes(["e", "l", "l"]);
// [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function like `getRangeIndexes` as below..

```
void main() {
  List<String> fullStringList = ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"];
  List<String> subStringList = ["e", "l", "l"];
  print(getRangeIndexes(fullStringList, subStringList)); //<-- prints [1, 3]
}

List<int> getRangeIndexes(List<String> fullList, List<String> subList){
  List<int> rangeIndexes;
  String fullString = fullList.join("");
  String subString = subList.join("");
  if(!fullString.contains(subString)){
    rangeIndexes = [-1, -1];            //return [-1, -1] when it does not contain the same sequence
  }
  else{
    int startIndex = fullString.indexOf(subString);
    int endIndex = startIndex + (subString.length - 1);
    rangeIndexes = [startIndex, endIndex];
  }
  return rangeIndexes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

`theList.indexOf(subListOfTheList.first);`

to get the index of the first element of secondlist in the first list, likewise for the last element in the second list.

`theList.indexOf(subListOfTheList.last);`

**OR**
make it a method

```
///gives you List of indexes of all the items in smalllist as they appear in biglist,respects the order
List<int> giveBackTheIndexes<T>(List<T> main, List<T> sub) {
  var biglist = main;
  var smalllist = sub;
  final indexes = <int>[];
  smalllist.forEach((smalllistElement) {
    var i = biglist.indexOf(smalllistElement);
    indexes.add(i);
    if(i!=-1){
      biglist[i]=null;
    }
  });
  return indexes;
}
```

if the value is -1 then item does not exists in the biglist

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah, it works for me, but it may not work in some situations

Comment: some situations like what?

Comment: above methods will ease your problem

Comment: I think this will be wrong in the very example which OP has posted in the question. In all these methods, it will always give `2` as the index of `l` because `indexOf` returns the index of first occurrence. Whereas it should be `3`. Because we would want the index of the second `l` which is `3`, not `2`.

Comment: This modified method is returning `{e: -1, l: -1}` for the same example. Isn't that wrong?

Comment: sorry i removed the wrong method, skipped the basic rule of Maps